# can anybody suggest alignment not properly coming in child table

Tags: html, css, html-table

can anybody suggest alignment not properly coming in child table.In myapplication having 10 columns in parent table. In child table value alignment are not coming properly  for header in parent .Can anybody suggest

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> header1 </th>
    <th> header2 </th>
    <th> header3</th>
    <th> header4</th>
    <th> header5</th>
    <th> header6</th>
    <th> header7</th>
    <th> header8</th>
    <th> header9</th>
    <th> header10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td colspan="8"> Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Test1 </td>
          <td>Test2 </td>
          <td>Test3 </td>
          <td>Test4 </td>
          <td>Test5 </td>
          <td>Test6 </td>
          <td>Test7 </td>
          <td>Test8 </td>
          <td>Test9 </td>
          <td>Test10 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I use bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

Your cells should be on the same hierarchy in order for the `colspan` property to take place as you expect.

Just remove the nested `<table>`:

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> header1 </th>
    <th> header2 </th>
    <th> header3</th>
    <th> header4</th>
    <th> header5</th>
    <th> header6</th>
    <th> header7</th>
    <th> header8</th>
    <th> header9</th>
    <th> header10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td colspan="8"> Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td>Test2 </td>
    <td>Test3 </td>
    <td>Test4 </td>
    <td>Test5 </td>
    <td>Test6 </td>
    <td>Test7 </td>
    <td>Test8 </td>
    <td>Test9 </td>
    <td>Test10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following style will keep your html code as it is.

```html
<style>
  th, td {
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> header1 </th>
    <th> header2 </th>
    <th> header3</th>
    <th> header4</th>
    <th> header5</th>
    <th> header6</th>
    <th> header7</th>
    <th> header8</th>
    <th> header9</th>
    <th> header10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td colspan="8"> Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Test1 </td>
          <td>Test2 </td>
          <td>Test3 </td>
          <td>Test4 </td>
          <td>Test5 </td>
          <td>Test6 </td>
          <td>Test7 </td>
          <td>Test8 </td>
          <td>Test9 </td>
          <td>Test10 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for nested table..!! Apply width 100% of a child table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> header1 </th>
    <th> header2 </th>
    <th> header3</th>
    <th> header4</th>
    <th> header5</th>
    <th> header6</th>
    <th> header7</th>
    <th> header8</th>
    <th> header9</th>
    <th> header10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td colspan="8"> Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10">
      <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>Test1 </td>
          <td>Test2 </td>
          <td>Test3 </td>
          <td>Test4 </td>
          <td>Test5 </td>
          <td>Test6 </td>
          <td>Test7 </td>
          <td>Test8 </td>
          <td>Test9 </td>
          <td>Test10 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: @Norman Riaz If content  is larege or small for header it is not working

Comment: i didn't get your point. nested table will get width of parent table.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to remove the child table and simply have 3 rows. The code goes as:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px solid black" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th> header1 </th>
    <th> header2 </th>
    <th> header3</th>
    <th> header4</th>
    <th> header5</th>
    <th> header6</th>
    <th> header7</th>
    <th> header8</th>
    <th> header9</th>
    <th> header10</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td colspan="8"> Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test1 </td>
    <td>Test2 </td>
    <td>Test3 </td>
    <td>Test4 </td>
    <td>Test5 </td>
    <td>Test6 </td>
    <td>Test7 </td>
    <td>Test8 </td>
    <td>Test9 </td>
    <td>Test10 </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```